# AuraEnable(cacheable=true) Across Multiple Sessions

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Does `@AuraEnable(cacheable=true)` save across multiple days and sessions? or does it save just for every session individually?

Comment: Caching is typically for a short period in any given session. The caching is applied client-side for periods like 30 seconds.

Comment: @PhilW there's no guarantee of how long the cache persists and can change between releases. That said, you're generally correct in the sense that it will only last for seconds to minutes, and definitely not across days or sessions.